# Writing OAuth provider in Python: guide + libraries?

Tags: python, oauth

I am looking to implement a OAuth v1 provider in Python (yes, independent of GAE and Django). The best thing I could come up with was to use this library:

https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

But it lacks docs other than a mock server and datastore. Is there a better approach:

- A guide on how to write an OAuth provider in Python?
- A better-documented and tested library?

Comment: I came across a similar Stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481468/oauth2-python-provider They mention http://pydanny.com/the-sorry-state-of-python-oauth-providers.html and https://github.com/idan/oauthlib. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/python/oauth/? It has both client and server code.

Answer (score 0):

[oauthlib](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib) is a well documented library that helps you [implement an OAuth 1.0 provider](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth1/server.html). I haven't tried the provider part, but I've used the OAuth client code via [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib).